# HSQLDB : user lacks privilege or object not found: USERS

Tags: java, hsqldb

I am using `HSQLDB` along with `Spring`. Whenever I try to execute an insert statement I get the error `user lacks privilege or object not found: USERS`.

The `USERS` table clears exists in the `HSQLDB Database` yet I am encountering this error.

`HSQLDB Configuration`

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:."/>
    <property name="username" value="SA"/>
    <property name="password" value=""/>
  </bean>
```

OffersDAO.java

```
    public class OffersDAO {

    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public void setDataSource(DataSource dataSource) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    }

    public void addUser(String email, String password) {

        String sql = "INSERT INTO USERS(EMAIL, PASSWORD) VALUES(?, ?)";

        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, email, password);

        System.out.println("ADDED USER : " + email + " , " + password);


    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Are you sure its connecting to right database ?

Answer (score 1):

The URL, "jdbc:hsqldb:mem:." means an in-memory database that is visible within the Java process that connects to it. When you start DatabaseManager separately from your program, the same URL creates a different database within the DatabaseManager's Java proecess.

Use an HSQLDB server to access a database from two different processes.

Answer (score 0):

HSQLDB has default schema called PUBLIC. All SQL queries will be pointing to PUBLIC; If you have created your own schema like eg:*OWNSCHEMA* then edit the xxx.script and change the following line

SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA PUBLIC

to

SET DATABASE DEFAULT INITIAL SCHEMA OWNSCHEMA